# Cant view Geofire database

Tags: firebase, geofire

https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java/tree/master/examples/SFVehicles

how can I view this? https://publicdata-transit.firebaseio.com/_geofire

i want to know where the app gets the coordinates of nearby places

Answer (score 1):

Hii this is just link of SFVehicles project in developer's firebase console ,opening it will take you to your own firebase console as you don't have the same project in your console.
you can try creating a dummy project with dummy data node and use that link to test this app.